# Android Studio not showing properties

Tags: android-studio, properties

I am experiencing a strange problem with Android Studio 2.2.3. No matter which widget is selected in Design View, the Properties View doesn't show the properties - it simply appears as shown below. If I click "View all properties" it goes completely empty.

How can I show the properties?

[image: Properties view]

Comment: I have the same problem on this version. Sometimes, i need to restart Android Studio, then properties appears.

Comment: I was in this situation but the top answer on this post helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135329/missing-attributes-in-layout-editor-in-android-studio/53173764#53173764

Comment: For me this happens, when I try to search for something in Attributes. After I when I type a letter and delete it, the Attributes are shown again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing attributes in layout editor in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135329/missing-attributes-in-layout-editor-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 15):

Restarting doesn't help. But after searching other Android Studio problems I found something that does work: File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Comment: Is there a way to bring properties view back? Restarting whole IDE just to do that is a bit harsh.

Comment: I have this issue, but 'Invalidate Caches and Restart' doesn't make any difference. I *have* noticed that the properties are displayed correctly for my top-level XML component (ScrolLView) but are not displayed for child components.

Comment: I've created an issue-report for Android Studio in case anyone wants to follow up:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112567920

Comment: Restarting IDE works for me, but agree with @AlexKravets there should be something lighter to restart / refresh only particular views

Answer (score 7):

I have seen the same issue, Here is the fix: GOTO **File > Invalidate Caches > Restart**. After restart note that it takes a little more time to start but this will surely fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

One way I find to solve the problem, go to the little setting button on top right corner of "Attributes"->> "Attached side"->> "none", and everything shows. Try it!!

Answer (score 2):

Window -> Restore Default Layout

Comment: If not working directly, you may need to click on some views

Answer (score 1):

So after some trail and error,

I have found the solution of this problem, just update gradle version 3.0.1 and used sdk version 26, this worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the suggestions posted here and none of them worked. Even just reinstalling Android Studio didn't work.

You could try this:

1. uninstall Android Studio
2. delete the C:/Users/xxx/.gradle and
   C:/Users/xxx/.AndroidStudiox.x folders which the installer left out
3. reinstall Android Studio.

It works and everything's back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

File->> Sync Project With Gradle Files 
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Tool menu and here you see xml Action menu and just click Genrate Schema from xml file so it can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I did not need to reinstall Android Studio. Invalidating cache/restarting did not work. So I ended up deleting `C:\Users\{your user here}\.AndroidStudio{version}`. I had two AndroidStudio folders with different versions and deleted both of them. After starting Android studio all settings will be restored to default and you will have to select theme and etc. You do not need to delete gradle folder.

Answer (score 0):

Close android studio

C:\Users\user name.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches

delete everything inside the project cashes folder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I installed android studio in my new PC and I found the solution.
My **NDK** was not completely installed or maybe it was corrupted so most of attributes were missing.
I reinstalled my NDK and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

(compileSdk and targetSdk in gradle) You may have increased the values. Specify a lower version. And File > Invalidate Caches > invalidate and restart

Comment: But why to decrease it again, any specific reason for this?

Comment: I don't actually know if there is a specific reason for this. While testing, only this worked.

Answer (score 0):

After I did all the suggestions.
I fixed this by clicking "Help" -> "Check for updates" and just update.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If any does not work, try changing your target sdk and compile sdk to 32. Then change your minsdk to 22 and sync the gradle files. This should be done in the build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Iave been get same problem but I'm found solution:
Got gradle file:
Change
CompileSdkVersion to lower from existing,and sync.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).