# Textview properties not showing in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm a beginner and I'm new to android development. I can't modify the `textview` properties, even after manually modifying in `XML` it's not showing up. I tried clicking the blue arrows it's not showing anything.

**This is how it currently looks like:**

[image]

**I want the properties to show like this:**

[image]

Edit1:
    Xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.robpercival.demoapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Great App"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="#080808"
    android:background="#2cfb03"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

By text view properties I mean textcolor, size, gravity, padding etc

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: can you post your xml code? And what do your mean by properties?

Comment: Post your xml please.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here but on the lower left there is a tab called Text select that and you will be able to change properties manually.

Comment: It seems the project is not loaded correctly . Try Build > Clean Project. And Re-Build project after cleaning.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify my problem clearly.                    I'm actually having same problem as this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637499/android-studio-not-showing-properties

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Starting to think this might be a bug in Android Studio. I've tried clearing my cache, rebuilding, etc. 

In some of my layouts, the Attributes window populates correctly when I select a TextView. In other layouts, the Attributes window stays blank after selecting a TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if no need background color, 
remove it `android:background="#2cfb03"`

above text show on center of the screen, use this inside textview property

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

[image]

Comment: My problem is not that, I'm actually having same problem as this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637499/android-studio-not-showing-properties