# attributes of widgets are not showing in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

my android studo 3.0.1 is not showing attributes of any widgets (e.g. textview, edittext, button, etc)

I have saw the post here 
[same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637499/android-studio-not-showing-properties) but file->invalidate and restart didn't solved my problem. Can someone please help me what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

So after some trail and error,

I have found the solution of this problem, just update gradle version and use latest sdk version,
this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same issue, but after searching other Android Studio problems I found something that does work: GOTO **File > Invalidate Caches > Restart**. After restart note that it takes a little more time to start but this will surely fix your issue.