# Android Studio not showing attributes for button

Tags: android, android-studio, button, gradle, attributes

I opened a blank Android application in Android Studio and when I attempt to edit a button, the attributes are not present. I'm new to Android development and following a guide which shows how to change the text in the button, but the attributes menu lacks the options seen in the guide.

Using:

- Android Studio 3.2.1
- Gradle 4.6 (Updated from 4.5)
- Android Plugin Version 3.2.1
- Windows 10

I updated Gradle and did Invalidate Caches/Restart with no change to the interface.

How my interface looks:

[image]

How the interface **should** look:

[image]

[A similar situation that did not resolve my issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637499/android-studio-not-showing-properties)

The revlavent XML file which was created via Android Studio's default file templet

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".MainActivity">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
              android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
              android:text="@string/button"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editText"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="textPersonName"
              android:text="Name"
              tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="181dp"
              tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="337dp" />
      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Double check your button Text color is not the same as your button background

Comment: I wouldn't be able to change the text color if I wanted too as the attribute to change such a value is not present.

Here is an example with plain text https://i.imgur.com/BXLi1nq.png

Comment: can post your layout `.xml` file?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for https://i.imgur.com/HjOZgeA.png

Bare in mind this is a blank file freshly created using Android Studio's default file.

Comment: don't post image here, but update your questions with the text content.

Comment: Updated post. Also thank you for posting my images. It was bothering me not being allowed to post images due to being new.

Comment: Noticed that there is a minus `-` in the second line of your xml file, try to remove it to see anything will happen.

Comment: I originally opened the code in IE to quickly copy it, I opened it in Atom this time to edit it, and that minus is not present. I updated the code to show it better and hopefully more accurately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try this first check if there is any anomaly in your XML code!
if yes then fix it first and then 
**GOTO File > Invalidate Caches and Restart.** After restart note that it takes a little more time to start but this will surely fix your issue.

and if that does not then use this

> EXTREME STEP

Well there are plenty of solutions to deal with android studio designView Rendering.

what i used to do in my utmost cases when i was kind of on low spec system is something like this

if WINDOWS is your OS then just follow the steps:

**1:**  Close your Android studio if running

**2:**  Make sure no shortcut icon is present in the bottomBar or desktop(optional)

**3:**  Open C:/Users/{your_USER_NAME}/ and just delete .AndroidStudio{VERSIONCODE} folder

> what does this folder do? well it saves your custom android studio
>   themes, styles, shortcuts etc

after deleting it

**4:** Check you are connected to Internet

**5:** open the android studio and it should present you with again setting screens like what theme you would like to use etc! just go with recommended

**6:** follow the recommended steps at first after that  if anything android studio is missing it will download!

**7:** try creating a new project then!

> **REMEMBER** you do not need to remove .gradle for just simple UI/UX glitches of android studio! just remove .androidStudo3.*.(*

Comment: Thank you! Removing the .AndroidStudio folder resolved the issue.

I loaded the most default settings I could including using not Darula (ew) and whatever was the default Android version it wanted. The attributes showed up properly. Then I opened the project I was already working on, and the attributes persisted.

I will keep that trick in my bag for the future headache inducing issue.

Comment: please upvote and accept the answer then! thanks @Ciccarello

Comment: @Ciccarello glad that it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, it is fixable. I usually get this problem when i have too big .xml files.

**First solution (Online)**
Just delete the following folder.

> C:/Users/USER_NAME/.AndroidStudio3.x

If you have more than one, you usually have to delete just the newest one. The other ones aren't usually used anyway.

**Second solution (Offline)** Create a new Project and just copy all the needed files inside.

Answer (score 0):

of your backup of the .idea folder within the project. Replace all files inside. Then open the project and Sync Project with gradle files.

Comment: seems like the beginning of the first sentence is missing