# I cant see attributes

Tags: android

I am new on android studio. since the second day I have a bug that I don't understand how to solve. I can't see any text title, color, text size etc. when I click attributes. how can I figure out this problem? Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH9hi.png)

Comment: I suggest you to start with basic videos about android studio and how you can work with the program. For example try this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFlPARW5IX8 .  Things are explained pretty well

Comment: what bug ??????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio not showing properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637499/android-studio-not-showing-properties)