# android studio doesn't show some attributes

Tags: java, android-studio

some attributes doesn't show up in the attributes bar.
I have like to write most of them in the xml code file by myself for every item in the design screen.
dies anyone have solution for this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQOra.png)

Comment: try File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637499/android-studio-not-showing-properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio not showing properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637499/android-studio-not-showing-properties)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.